# What does this B'z Rubik's Cube look like when solved?

Tags: rubiks-cube

What does this B'z Rubik's Cube look like when solved?
Also, how should I "transform" it for my 7-year-old son in order to solve it using a Rubik's cube solver?

Pictures below show all six faces.
https://jp.mercari.com/item/m62241583428

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Here an auction that shows one more of the faces.](https://www.carousell.com.my/p/rubik-s-cube-b-z-cube-japanese-singer-very-rare-1136546816/) I've been unable to find a picture with all six faces, though. Since you have the cube, I would just solve it following a tutorial, then you know what it looks like from all six faces. ;) As for your other question, I would mostly just look at the colors, since they seem to be uniqu per face: red; yellow; green; blue; the faces we can see in both auction pictures; and one mystery remaining face for the left-over pieces.

Comment: I count 16 human faces- hard to tell which goes where. You should formulate your comment into an answer- I am not too fussy about being from a primary source.